# Up and Down with verbs

Tags: verbs

I've noticed that many verbs can use both **up** and **down**, but it seems some can use only one of the two. Why so? Does it have to do it with the definition of a certain verb?

For instance we can say:

- Put up/down, Place up/down, Throw up/down

But we can's say:

- Drop up, Lift down, Raise down

Comment: ***Drop up*** means to visit a place:  https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/drop+up - ***Lift down*** means to pick up (something) in order to move it to a lower position - https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/Lift+down - Raise can be followed by down, but it is not an idiomatic expression - https://www.google.it/search?q=%22raise+down%22&lr=lang_en&dcr=0&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:1994,cd_max:2008,lr:lang_1en&tbm=bks&prmd=ivn&ei=xQYXWvzeFs75kwWhuoawAg&start=10&sa=N&biw=768&bih=1004&dpr=2

Comment: You can't because there is a contradiction in terms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Raise down" cannot be used. What user159691 is Googling are situations in which the verb "raise" is being used and then followed by an adverb / preposition "down", but are unrelated to each other except that they "collocate":

> "The structure is going to be **raised** *down there* in Arizona."
>   ("down there" means "to the south of us" or "below us"; in this situation "to
>   the south of us")

As for your question, Alexander, "up" and "down" in these situations are particles (also classified as functors) used in phrasal verbs in English. The verbs they modify don't quite mean the same without them.  Usually, these occur because English is missing an exact verb to describe the action or the verb that can be used is uncommon; it could also be a common verb that could be used therein, but it's just not common in that sort of expression:

"I have **looked up** the word in the dictionary." (phrasal verb: very common)

"I have **searched** for the word in the dictionary." (not very common use here)

"I have **put up** *with* you long enough." (phrasal verb: very common)

"I have **tolerated** you long enough." (not very common)

The "up" or "down" is a particle, so it has no real meaning; it just modifies the word.  Again, English speakers use these phrasal verbs because English either does not have an exact verb for the situation or the verb is not a common one used in everyday speech or the verb that is common in speech is just, for some reason, not commonly used in this situation. I would be shocked if I heard someone say "I *searched* for the word in the dictionary" rather than "I *looked up* the word in the dictionary."

I hope that might have helped you out, Alexander.  Take care and you can ask me any question that you might have and I'll try to answer it.  If I can't answer it, I'm sure someone else will be able to.

Comment: I clearly stated that “raise down” is not idiomatic and the combination of the two terms is just random, with no specific meaning. As for “put up”, the phrasal  verb is “***put up with***”.

Comment: I think it's "put up" and it's intransitive. The "with" is used as the preposition instransitively here. We can agree to disagree. I know what you said, but I didn't think it was clear from your answer, so I've clarified it for Alexander.

Comment: Put up with: https://dictionary.cambridge.org/it/dizionario/inglese/put-up-with-sth-sb - https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/put-up-with - https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/put-up-with

Comment: Congrats. I agree that it is always "put up with", but I still think it can be treated as an intransitive phrasal verb too; it is one that cannot be used without "with".

Comment: For starters, I was trying to show Alexander the particle "up" so "with" does not matter anyway. He is asking about the particles "up" and "down", so "with" does not matter therein. I don't see why we are arguing about this.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I really don’t understand the question.

Comment: No, I think you understand the question and you've answered it well above. He wants to know about the particles "up" and "down" in phrasal verbs; why do we say them? I don't really know, but I tried to show that they are used with verbs that are more common in English, so that may be the reason. It's easier to say "put up (with)" than to say "tolerate" because we say "put" all the time; "tolerate" isn't an everyday word.

Comment: http://homes.chass.utoronto.ca/~cpercy/courses/6361lamont.html

Comment: @user159691 and Nicholas Castagnola: "put up" does not always need "with", as in the challenge **put up or shut up**.

Comment: @WeatherVane - yes, but my remark was about the specific usage Nicholas did in his example sentence, where the phrasal verb is clearly “put up with”,  not “put up.”

Comment: This is true, but, again, I didn't care whether it was "put up" or "put up with" because Alexander's question was about the particle "up" in phrasal verbs in general; therefore, I was only focusing on "up".